# Can't get Properties of a Specific Child Page

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I just started using `umbraco` 4 days ago and I'm stuck with this problem.

I have a page named `"About Us"` that is a child under `"Home"` and I need to get some of its properties in the `"Home"` Page.

I created a partial view macro to do this but I get the error loading partial view script instead.

Below is my code:

```
@{ var selection = CurrentPage.Children.Where(x => x.Name == "aboutus"); }

@if (selection.Any())
{
    <ul>
        @foreach (var item in selection)
        {
            <div class="sc-inner">
                <h4>
                   @item.PageTitle</h4>
                <p>
                   @Umbraco.Truncate(@item.mainAboutDescription, 100)</p>
                <a class="btn btn-danger" href="@item.Url">Read More...</a>
            </div>
            break;
        }
    </ul>
}
```

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Edits:
The error on the website I got is below;

Error loading Partial View script (file: ~/Views/MacroPartials/homePage_aboutUsSection.cshtml)

Comment: could you please post the error

Comment: @Anth12, Thanks for reponding. Please see edited question.

Comment: The error is being surpressed by Umbraco with a generic message (errors can be enabled from the config/Umbraco.config). Just a comment, you have `div` elements nested within a `ul` you should use `li` instead or change the `ul`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the partial is inheriting `UmbracoTemplatePage` the `CurrentPage` property is a `dynamic`, you cannot use lambda expressions as an argument to a dynamically dispatched operation.

If you wish to use Linq to query the content use `Model.Content` rather than `CurrentPage` which is an `IPublishedContent` e.g.

```
@{ var selection = Model.Content.Children.Where(x => x.Name == "aboutus"); }
```

*Note: the `Name` property will return the documents Name as entered in the CMS most likely 'About Us' instead of 'aboutus'*

Using the about will return an `IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>` so you will need to use the `GetPropertyValue` method rather than accessing the content dynamically:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage

@{ var selection = Model.Content.Children.Where(x => x.Name == "aboutus"); }

@if (selection.Any())
{
    <ul>
        @foreach (var item in selection)
        {
            <li class="sc-inner">
                <h4>
                    @item.GetPropertyValue("pageTitle")
                </h4>
                <p>
                    @Umbraco.Truncate(@item.GetPropertyValue<string>("mainAboutDescription"), 100)
                </p>
                <a class="btn btn-danger" href="@item.Url">Read More...</a>
            </li>
            break;
        }
    </ul>
}
```

Comment: Oh thank you very much for your explanation. I am in your debt. And the point where you mentioned the name property could be returned as "About Us" and not "aboutus" as I specified earlier worked. Thanks a billion.

Comment: Great, no problem.

Answer (score 2):

Very bad practice to use the Name property for querying in your code - what if somebody changes the Name to `About` for example. Your code would break.  If there is something else that is unique on the node then it would be better.

For example if you have an aboutUs document type for your about us page you could use:

```
Model.Content.Children.Where(x => x.DocumentTypeAlias == "exactNameOfYourDocTypeAliasHere")
```

or, although not so robust, the Id of the page could be used.

```
Model.Content.Children.Where(x => x.Id == 1234)
```

The Id is far less likely to change than the Name of a key page like this.

I would generally not use the Id in code either but it is far better than Name